# R shiny: how to specify a selectInput in html?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would need to specify some selectInput() in html (in order to insert them in a data frame).

The reproducible code here below does not provide me with a selectInput. What is in the HTML() is a copy-paste from a html code of a selectInput() that I obtained using 'Inspect element' (and this is probably why it's not working, but I can't fix it unfortunately)

```
shiny::runApp(
list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("TEST"),

sidebarPanel(
helpText('This does not work:')
),

mainPanel(    
HTML("<label class='control-label' for='variable' style = 'width:400px;'>Variable:</label>
<select id='variable' tabindex='-1' class='selectized shiny-bound-input' style='display: none;'><option value='toz' selected='selected'></option></select>  
<div class='selectize-control single'><div class='selectize-input items full has-options has-items'><div data-value='toz' class='item'>Cyl</div><input type='text' autocomplete='off' tabindex='' style='width: 4px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: -10000px;'></div><div class='selectize-dropdown single' style='display: none; width: 893px; top: 36px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;'><div class='selectize-dropdown-content'><div data-value='toz' data-selectable='' class='option selected'>Cyl</div><div data-value='toztoz' data-selectable='' class='option'>Trans</div><div data-value='ge' data-selectable='' class='option'>Gea</div></div></div></div>
<script data-for='variable' type='application/json'>{}</script>")   

)
)
, 

server = function(input,output){      
}
)
)
```

Thank you in advance
Cheers

Comment: You can't randomly copy code from a web page and expect it to do what you want :/

Comment: Please include your actual code or reproducible example, a more specific question besides "what's wrong here", and/or the things you've tried thus far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the source code is very useful to see how it is built, however I don't recommend you to copy an entire section of code for reuse it as is. Use the shiny functions.

But if you want to build your select input with the HTML syntax, you can simply use the HTML select tag :

```
mainPanel(    
  HTML("<select id='select'>
          <option value='cyl'>Cyl</option>
          <option value='trans'>Trans</option>
          <option value='gea'>Gea</option>
        </select>")
)
```

Btw, in the code you copied : `style='display: none;'` hide the element (but anyway this code can't work as is).

Comment: Brilliant ! thanks ! I think that I am slowly progressing / I understand better by the day, also this is also thanks to your answers !